# Scrapy returns no data from css path

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape the links (or rather the listing IDs) to the listings on the first page of this [website](https://www.studenten-wg.de/angebote_lesen.html?detailsuche=aus&stadt=D%FCsseldorf&fuer=Wohnungen).
I think the right css selector must be

```
div.property-content-list > div.property-text > h3 > a::attr(href)
```

At least when I search for this selector (without the `::attr(href)`) in the Element Inspector, it seems like it should return the correct data. However, when running the spider, I get an empty output.

I am new to scrapy and css selectors but figured it out for most other websites. Where is my mistake with this one?

For reference, this is the parse method of my spider.

```
    def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.property-content-list > div.property-text > h3 > a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield {
            "href": quote
                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On your website, all the listings pages follow the same naming pattern `mietangebot_ID.html`. You don't really need to use CSS selectors to get the IDs.

You can check it for yourself by running this Bash command:

```
curl -s "https://www.studenten-wg.de/angebote_lesen.html?detailsuche=aus&stadt=D%FCsseldorf&fuer=Wohnungen" | grep -Eo "mietangebot_[0-9]+\.html"
```

It prints the following:

```
mietangebot_1892908.html
mietangebot_1892908.html
mietangebot_1892908.html
mietangebot_1866908.html
[...]
```

In your scraper, you can simply use `re.findall()` with the naming pattern and capture the ID as a group:

```
import re

listings_ids = re.findall(r"mietangebot_([0-9]+)\.html", response.text)
print(listings_ids)
```

Which will print your listings:

```
['1891640', '1860266', etc...]
```

Comment: thanks! using regex seems like a good option here.
I am not sure about the implementation still. I put the findall() method before the for loop and adjusted the for loop to iterate through the list. But I still get an empty string - any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you are not on the right page? Could you try to print `response.text`?